# Error executing TFS command

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, tfs, tfs-sdk

I have an exception when calling `Workspace.Merge`. I am getting access to `VersionControlExt`
from VisualStudio. The code below gets access to Visual Studio TFS explorer window object (that is active in the environment and user is logged in).

```
VersionControlExt vce;
vce = _applicationObject.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt") as VersionControlExt;

MergeCandidate[] candidates = version.GetMergeCandidates(source, dest, RecursionType.Full);
Workspace ws = vce.Explorer.Workspace;

foreach (MergeCandidate mc in candidates)
{
 string comment = mc.Changeset.Comment;
 ChangesetVersionSpec csvs = new ChangesetVersionSpec(mc.Changeset.ChangesetId);


// HERE NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION IS THROWN
GetStatus gs = ws.Merge(source, dest, csvs, csvs, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full, MergeOptionsEx.None);
}
```

Exception Details

> TargetSite: {System.String
>   get_AuthorizedUser()}

StackTrace

> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer.get_AuthorizedUser()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.get_DisplayName()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.RequireLocal()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Merge(ItemSpec
>   source, String targetPath, VersionSpec
>   versionFrom, VersionSpec versionTo,
>   LockLevel lockLevel, MergeOptionsEx
>   mergeOptions, String[]
>   propertyNameFilters)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Merge(ItemSpec
>   source, String targetPath, VersionSpec
>   versionFrom, VersionSpec versionTo,
>   LockLevel lockLevel, MergeOptionsEx
>   mergeOptions)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.Merge(String
>   sourcePath, String targetPath,
>   VersionSpec versionFrom, VersionSpec
>   versionTo, LockLevel lockLevel,
>   RecursionType recursion,
>   MergeOptionsEx mergeOptions)\r\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. In order to use TFS functionality one needs to reference Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll. I have both 9.0 Studio and 10.0 Studio installed. I have referenced dlls from 10.0 while actually using 9.0 studio. Stupid mistake but it has taken hours to debug.

Answer (score 1):

What is the exception's Type and Message?

What version of Team Explorer locally? What version of TFS server?

Given `get_AuthorizedUser` at top of stack, I suspect this is the TFS client failing to authenticate—start by checking the current directory is in a mapped workspace and the current user is authorized on TFS.

Comment: There;s a problem with this call

Comment: @CaptainComic: As you've said. Please expand on what the problem is and the environment in which it is happening. (Reading http://tinyurl.com/so-hints will help.)